# how to convert datetimepicker date (bootstrap 4) format 16/07/2019 10:00 to mysql format 2019-07-16 10:00 with laravel (5.8) Carbon

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

hello friends I have a problem with the dates pause .. in my view I have a datetimepicker of (bootstrap 4) with the format 12/06/2019 12:00:00 and what I need is to pass it to the format that accepts mysql 2019-06-12 12:00:00

try to do it from js but it did not work

```js
$(function () {
        $('#startdate').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        format: 'Y-MM-D H:mm',
        autoclose:true,
        minDate: moment()
});
```

that's how I'm trying from my controller but it has given me an error :(

```
$promociones->fecha_inicio = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$request->fecha_inicio)->toDateTimeString();
    $promociones->fecha_fin = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$request->fecha_fin)->toDateTimeString();
```

the error
[image: the error]

Comment: an error? pls, show it.

Comment: In "app.php" the timezone is set this way: 'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to investigate a lot and be trial and error but I managed to solve my problem ... thank you very much to all of you who helped me in providing ideas for my solution. Thanks for your help, it helped me a lot to solve my problem.

I started fixing my datetimepicker so

```
$('#startdate').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: moment()
    });
    $('#enddate').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: moment()
    });
```

I had to remove the format I had given him....after that pass to the controller
as some suggested to me ... pass the format that was receiving my input that is d / m / YH: m after that I passed the time zone of my country (in case there was a problem of dates) then I just had to pass the format with which I wanted to save it to the database in my case mysql by default accepts the format Ymd H: i ... and ready problem solved

```
$promociones->fecha_inicio = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',$request->fecha_inicio,'America/El_Salvador')->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    $promociones->fecha_fin = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',$request->fecha_fin,'America/El_Salvador')->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use this

`\Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->fecha_inicio);` OR `Carbon::parse($request->fecha_inicio);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the incoming format with `Carbon::createFromFormat()`, not the outgoing format.

```php
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i','16/07/2019 10:00')->toDateTimeString();
```

I'm assuming the first digits are days based on the title since there is no 16th month.  It's impossible to tell from `12/06/2019 12:00:00`.

EDIT (timezone issue)

Since you say the timezone is set in `config/app.php`, it's also possible to pass the timezone as the third parameter:

```php
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i','16/07/2019 21:37','America/El_Salvador')->toDateTimeString();
```

Also, if you have recently made changes to the config, you may need to run:

```php
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: friend with what you recommended me this error arose ...Unknown or bad timezone (16/07/2019 21:37:00)

Comment: Do you have a valid timezone set in `config/app.php`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Try passing the timezone as the third parameter.  `$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s','16/07/2019 21:37:00','America/El_Salvador')->toDateTimeString();`

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan config:clear` to clear the config cache?

Comment: still giving the same error :( ... I'll try with strtotime to see if I succeed (the problem is in updating the dates)

Answer (score 0):

List timezone: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

```
$promociones->fecha_inicio = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$request->fecha_inicio)->toDateTimeString();
$promociones->fecha_fin = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$request->fecha_fin)->toDateTimeString();
```

***In "config/app.php" the timezone is set this way: 'timezone' => '...'***

**Ex:**

`'timezone' => 'America/Guatemala'`

Thanks

Comment: I already set it to my time zone and it keeps giving me the same error :(